# P5.js How to rotate a text with each charatcer rotating differently and moving in the same time

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I tried to rotate and move each character at the same time(text() is called differently for each character) but it kinda freaks out because I need to rotate those characters by its own origin. When the character reaches the canvas's border I need it to drop down. Can someone help me with it. Here is the code.

```
var font;
var c = [255, 255, 255];
var size = 64;
var xycoord = [45, 100, 155];
var x = 180;
var y = 320;
var bugs = [];
var numBugs = 40;
var clicked = Boolean(0);
var framesPast = 0;
var letters = ["R", "A", "G", "E"];
var texts = [];
var a = 5;
var transx = -40;
var transy = 60;
var movex = 0;
var movey = 0;
var moveyD = 0

function preload() {
  font = loadFont("fonts/Hunger Games.ttf");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  var text = textFont(font);
  angleMode(DEGREES);

}

function draw() {
   textSize(size);      
   background(0);

   if (clicked && framesPast < 50) {
    size = 128;
    c = [206, 0, 0];
    x += random(-3, 3);
    y += random(-3, 3);
    framesPast++;
  }
  if (framesPast >= 50 && clicked && x + movex >= 0) {
    push();
    rotate(a);
    drawWords(letters[0], c[0], c[1], c[2], x + movex, y + movey);
    movex -= 3;
    movey -= 3;
    a++;
    pop();
  } else if (clicked && x + movex <= 0) {
    drawWords(letters[0], c[0], c[1], c[2], 0, y + movey + moveyD);
    moveyD+=5;
  }
  if (framesPast < 50) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      drawWords(letters[i], c[0], c[1], c[2], x+xycoord[i], y);
    }
  }
  if (clicked) {
    x = 80;
    y = 320;
    xycoord = [0, 90, 195, 300];
  } else if (!clicked) {
    xycoord = [0, 45, 100, 155];
    size = 64;
    c = [255, 255, 255];
    x = 180;
    y = 320;
  }
}

function drawWords(word, r, g, b, corx, cory) {
  fill(r, g, b);
  text(word, corx, cory);
}

function mousePressed() {
  clicked = Boolean(1);
}

function mouseReleased(){
  clicked = Boolean(0)
}
```